# When is it prefrable to use a tape like Wigluv, rather than caulk or low expansion foam?

Tags: caulk, spray-foam, weather-resistant, tape

I'm trying to understand when to use what method to seal, to prevent air and/or water.
When would a tape like Wigluv be preferred over caulk or low expansion foam?  What applications is it the ideal choice?

Comment: "*air and/or water*"  Those are two very different things.  Is there a specific  situation you need to deal with?

Comment: Not really, Just trying to figure when a tape is preferable, over the other two.

Answer (score 1):

A thick tape like Wigluv would only be used where a flat surface isn't needed or any such bulge will be concealed.

Caulk would be used for small and shallow cracks or gaps (1/8th inch or less wide) and a flush or completely flat surface is needed.

Foam is for moderate to large gaps (1/4 to 3/4 inch, depending on foam type) and deep or full depth straight through filling.

Of course, all 3 can be used, or any combination of them, that addresses the need for a specific result or longevity.

Comment: Let's say we have a flat surface, without need for concealing, the gap 1/8th or less wide. Why would a person prefer the tape, to caulk?

Comment: Sounds like laziness and even ignorance to me. But, we are raised now to, laughably, believe plastic is forever and the best of the best. It's surely not the best nor is just tape the longest lived nor cheapest way to go. I would only use tape on-top-of caulk in that case for a treatment that could last a century. The tape or caulk alone won't last even half a century. But, caulk can be sealed quite well from drying out or suffering UV damage with just paint. I'm not so sure the tape can do that without caulk's protection of penetration. I'm not a fan of the Zip System either.

Answer (score 1):

You would prefer tape when you don't want to wait for caulking to cure or when applying to a gap of varying sizes where caulk is only suitable for part of the job.
Tape is likely faster than intermittent backer rods -- time is money.